# How to change a column's value according to If condition

Tags: sql

I have an order table in my sql database. Let say I want to check if the order date is less then 10/10/2003, then I want to change the Status From Active To Inactive. I am wondering if this is the correct syntax for doing this. Here is my table and my pseudocode but I am not sure how to convert it to SQL language

Order Table
[image]
Here is my pseudocode

```
Update orderTB
IF(OrderDate < '10/10/2003')
  Set Status = 'Inactive 
  WHERE Status = 'ACTIVE'
```

Expected Result
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the condition to `WHERE` like the other condition:

```
Update orderTB
  Set Status = 'Inactive'
  WHERE Status = 'ACTIVE'
    AND OrderDate < '10/10/2003'
```

Comment: Very Nice, Simple and Clear answer. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a quiet forward UPDATE-statement:

```
Update "orderTB" 
SET "Status" = 'Inactive' 
WHERE "OrderDate" < '10/10/2003' AND "Status" = 'ACTIVE';
```

But you should keep care of the date format. In this case it will make no big difference but 10/03/2003 can be very different. I recommend to use ISO format only -- but this is off topic to your question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :)